# Script to compare directories

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a Python script to compare the directories

Requirement is their are two files

Directory1 has contents

```
1.txt 
2.txt 
3.txt 
4.txt 
6.txt 
7.txt 
9.txt
```

Directory 2 has contents

```
1.txt 
2.txt 
3.txt 
4.txt 
5.txt 
6.txt 
7.txt 
8.txt 
9.txt
```

All the files inside the directory 2 has to be replaced to directory 1

For instance the output of directory1 should be replaced with contents inside directory2

```
 1.txt 
 2.txt 
 3.txt 
 4.txt 
 5.txt 
 6.txt 
 7.txt 
 8.txt 
 9.txt
```

The script I have is

```
import os, sys
import filecmp
import re
from distutils import dir_util
import shutil
holderlist=[]

def compareme(dir1, dir2):
    dircomp=filecmp.dircmp(dir1,dir2)
    only_in_one=dircomp.left_only
    diff_in_one=dircomp.diff_files
    dirpath=os.path.abspath(dir1)
    [holderlist.append(os.path.abspath( os.path.join(dir1,x) )) for x in only_in_one]
    [holderlist.append(os.path.abspath( os.path.join(dir1,x) )) for x in diff_in_one]
    if len(dircomp.common_dirs) > 0:
        for item in dircomp.common_dirs:
            compareme(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir1,item)), os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir2,item)))
        return holderlist
        print holderlist
def main():
 if len(sys.argv) > 3:
   dir1=sys.argv[1]
   dir2=sys.argv[2]
   dir3=sys.argv[3]
 else:
   print "Usage: ", sys.argv[0], "currentdir olddir difference"
   sys.exit(1)

 if not dir3.endswith('/'): dir3=dir3+'/'

 source_files=compareme(dir1,dir2)
 dir1=os.path.abspath(dir1)
 dir3=os.path.abspath(dir3)
 destination_files=[]
 new_dirs_create=[]
 for item in source_files:
   destination_files.append(re.sub(dir1, dir3, item) )
 for item in destination_files:
 new_dirs_create.append(os.path.split(item)[0])
 for mydir in set(new_dirs_create):
   if not os.path.exists(mydir): os.makedirs(mydir)

 copy_pair=zip(source_files,destination_files)
 for item in copy_pair:
   if os.path.isfile(item[0]):
    shutil.copyfile(item[0], item[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()
```

But it is not replacing the files as expected

Comment: Could you explain what troubleshooting steps you've tried so far, and what the results were?

Comment: This looks more like python-2.x to me, given your use of `print`.  Can you confirm?

Comment: Can't your script just copy the contents of Directory2 over to Directory1 and overwrite? If not, please provide more examples.

Comment: that's what i am not able to do

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete alle files in **Directory1**

   ```
     path = Directory1
     fnames = os.listdir(path)
     for fname in fnames:
         fpath = os.path.join(path, fname)
         if not stat.S_ISDIR(os.lstat(fpath).st_mode):
             os.remove(fpath)
   ```
2. Move all files from **Directory2**

   ```
   path = Directory2
   fnames = os.listdir(path)
   for fname in fnames:
       source_fpath = os.path.join(path, fname)
       if not stat.S_ISDIR(os.lstat(source_fpath).st_mode):
           target_fpath = os.path.join(Directoy1, fname)
           os.rename(source_fpath, target_fpath)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not clear why you use `dir3`, but I will just skip it since I think the goal is to transfer the differences at `dir1`. In case you want to move all the files from `dir2` to `dir1` I give the solution to this too.

```
import os
import sys
import shutil

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 3:
        dir1=sys.argv[1]
        dir2=sys.argv[2]
    else:
        print "Usage: ", sys.argv[0], "currentdir olddir"
        sys.exit(1)

    dir1_list = os.listdir(dir1)
    dir2_list = os.listdir(dir2)

    if dir1_list != dir2_list:
        # If you want the different files in dir1 do this:
        diff = list(set(dir2_list) - set(dir1_list))

        # If you want to move dir2 to dir1 do this:
        diff = dir2_list

        for file in diff:
            shutil.move(os.path.join(dir2, file), os.path.join(dir1, file))
```